# Access an iframe from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access an iframe from a chrome extension and I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://<website>" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ijlbgginkemmeidmhfhbgbbeiloofged/js/button.js:51:28)
```

**manifest :**

```
{
    "author": [{
        "name": "sjpcl"
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "shocko",
    "description": "extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
        "*://*/"
    ],
    "background":{
        "scripts" : ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*","<all_urls>","https://*/*"],
            "js": ["js/button.js","jquery.js","try.js" ],
            "css": ["css/style.css"],
            "all_frames": true

        }

    ]
}
```

The faulty code is here:

**button.js :**

```
var iframe=document.getElementById("uploader_iframe");

alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head").length);
```

I am using the following code on **another** iframe in the same page and I get no errors:

```
var iframe=document.getElementsByClassName("ifrm")[1];
alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head").length);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You can't directly access a cross-origin iframe DOM contents. You'll have to use messaging e.g. via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/postMessage) or chrome.runtime messaging (relayed via your background script) to coordinate the instances of your content script running in the main page and inside the iframe.

Comment: Can you please show me a sample code snippet? I'll be greatful

Comment: Without knowing what your extension does, how it interacts with the page and the user, I can't really be more helpful than the documentation I've linked.

Comment: so i just have to pass message to the backround , and the backround have to do the action with this iframe?

Comment: No, that's a different messaging method, which might not work for your extension.

Comment: so you can explain what will work for example?

Comment: I don't know what to explain in addition to the documentation without knowing what your extension does, how it interacts with the page and the user.

Comment: i just try to access the iframe and alert the number of  the "head" tag. wich is 1 . then i  succes to access the iframe i will be able to do the real job. so if you can give any hipotetic example . it will help very much

Comment: Let's hope someone else will help here. I can only answer a specific question where I know exactly what's happening.